# Intent from adapter: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

Reaching out to ask for your help on the following.

I have a RecyclerView and in my adapter I'm trying to start a new activity. But I'm getting the following error:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Here is my code:

```
private Context mContext;
```

...

```
public EntitiesListAdapter(ArrayList<Entity> myDataset, Context context) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    mContext = context;
}
```

...

```
holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ViewEntityActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("entity", row);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And I'm setting the adapter this way:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<EntitiesListAdapter.MyViewHolder> mAdapter = new EntitiesListAdapter(entities, getApplicationContext());
```

But already tried like `private Context context` and using `context` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Do you identify what I'm missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `mContext.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent)`

Comment: It throws the same error :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using your Adapter in your Activity then simply use:

```java
RecyclerView.Adapter<EntitiesListAdapter.MyViewHolder> mAdapter = new EntitiesListAdapter(entities, MainActivity.this);
```

If you want to use `getApplicationContext()`, then you have to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `startActivity`’s Intent like:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ViewEntityActivity.class);
intent.put("entity", row);
intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I don't know why the suggestion `RecyclerView.Adapter<EntitiesListAdapter.MyViewHolder> mAdapter = new EntitiesListAdapter(entities, MainActivity.this);` does not work. It throws the same error as before. I could move on with `intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`